# I don't understand onClick={() => onClick()} (beginner question)

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I'm creating one of my first apps in react. In my code you can find components of my app, those include buttons. The part of my code, that I don't understand is `onClick={() => onClick()}`. Can anyone in simple words explain to me, what exactly doing this code?

```
import './Button.scss';
import React from 'react';

export default function Button({ children, primary, bordered, onClick, type }) {
  return (
    <button
      className={`button ${primary ? 'primary' : ''} ${
        bordered ? 'bordered' : ''
      }`}
      onClick={() => onClick()}
      type={type ? type : 'button'}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

My idea is like "when you click on this, call function onClick (I didn't create any function like that)". This part of code simply confuse me.
Why writing `onClick={onClick}` is not right option?

Comment: When you click on the button then it will execute the ```onClick()``` function. The second one.

Comment: `onClick={onClick}` is essentially the same as what you have, and may well work completely fine. The only time it will make a difference is if the body of `onClick` uses the `this` keyword anywhere. (Which in React it quite often will.) [Edit: just realised this is a function component, not a class, in which case I don't believe there is any practical situation where there will be any difference.]

Comment: Thank you for your answers, im happy to know that there is not much difference for my app, from your explanation, i get that onClick={() => onClick()} is just better to use in any case, but functionality has no diffence right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a useful example to that notation, let's say you have two buttons (primary and regular) with the same `onClick` handler but you want to pass a parameter regarding which button you clicked:

`onClick={e => onClick(e, primary)}`

So your `onClick` handler could behave differently depending on which button you click.

Comment: Thank you for example explanation, helped me a lot :)